# Copy cells from one excel spreadsheet to another based on a value in the row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet, Sheet 1, with data in it taken by the minute. Each line row has a timestamp and the corrosponding data follows.

I have a second spreadsheet/sheet, Sheet 2, with accompanying weather data which is also timestamped in the same way.

Is there a way to append the cells from Sheet 2 based on the known timestamp into Sheet 1. Sheet 1 looks at time in its own cell, then searches Sheet2 for the same one and if it finds it, copies data from Sheet2 into itself.

```
Sheet 1
Time     Data1     Data2     Data3
09:54    A1        B1        C1
09:55    A2        B2        C2
...
13:18    AN        BN        CN

Sheet 2
Time     Data4     Data5     Data6
09:54    Z1        X1        Y1
09:55    Z2        X2        Y2
...
13:18    ZN        XN        YN
```

Such that Sheet 1 will end up looking like

```
Sheet 1
Time     Data1     Data2     Data3     Data4     Data 5     Data6
09:54    A1        B1        C1        Z1        X1         Y1
09:55    A2        B2        C2        Z2        X2         Y2 
...
13:18    AN        BN        CN        ZN        XN         YN
```

The problem I have is that, although I have weather data for every minute I don't have data for each minute in sheet 1. I have multiple 09:54 and 09:55 readings and jumps so I can't just copy and paste the lines 1-for-1.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What functions have you tried so far? This seems like a simple vlookup.

Answer (score 0):

**Write below written Formula in the Cell E2 of Sheet1**, and drag the cell pointer 2 cell right, then Press F2 and Finally finish it with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**. Then fill it down till is required. Sheet 1 will looks like Screen Shot below.

```
{=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A2:D5,{2,3,4},FALSE),"")}
```

[image]